# How to create a KTX2 cubemap texture from separate images using TOKTX

Tags: vulkan

I have recently been implementing a skybox using a KTX2 cubemap texture.  However I'm struggling to create a cubemap file from a list of images.  The SDK provides the TOKTX tool to create the file:

```
toktx --t2 --target_type RGBA --cubemap skybox.ktx2 posx.jpg negx.jpg posy.jpg negy.jpg posz.jpg negz.jpg
```

As far as I can tell this *should* generate a KTX2 image with 6 faces (or array layers in Vulkan parlance) comprising RGBA components.

However I get the following error:

```
toktx: "negx.jpg" has a different colortype_e (component count) than preceding files.
```

There does not appear to be any differences between the images.  Also the order of the images doesn't seem to matter, I get the same error on the second image in all cases.  I even get the error if I use the *same* image for every argument.

If I remove the `--target_type RGBA` argument the file is generated but of course it no longer has an alpha channel.  I *could* pre-process the images to inject an alpha channel, but that sort of makes the point of using KTX slightly redundant.

Finally I have tried existing RGBA cubemap images from the [Vulkan Samples Assets](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples-Assets) and they work in my demo code.  So I'm just struggling with building the cubemap myself.

I've tried searching for this error but to no avail - any suggestions?

Bonus question: A couple of the KTX cubemap files I tested against contained mipmaps, is there any logical reason for a skybox texture to be mipmapped?

Comment: Why are you using JPEG for your source texture data? As a lossy compression codec, it makes for a terrible starting point for your data. Can you obtain your images in something else? Also: "*but of course it no longer has an alpha channel*" JPEG doesn't support alpha. So if the output has an alpha, it would be 1.0 for all pixels.

Comment: The JPEG images were just the ones I already had (previously I'd loaded each image separately).  Yes of course I wouldn't use those images in the real world, but that doesn't explain why I was getting that error.  Note that the `--target_type RGBA` clause was added to inject the alpha channel since (as you point out) JPEG doesn't support alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding non-RGB source files to RGBA is not possible with toktx. For the cube maps in the Vulkan repository I used the [PowerVR texture tools](https://developer.imaginationtech.com/pvrtextool/). That tool has a small wizard to create a cubemap from size input images (including jpg files) and you can then use it to encode your cubemap to different formats including RGBA. If you want to fill alpha with a fixed color or load it from a different jpg, that's also possible with the PowerVR texture tools.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was expecting something along those lines.  I used the PowerVR tool as you suggested and it does the job nicely.  Cheers.

Comment: Thinking about it the tool should really just throw a more explicit error.  I'll raise a ticket because personally it was a legitimate use-case (albeit a daft one) but the response was just confusing, to me a least.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that needs a CLI solution. There's Khronos Group's `ktx create` and more.

- [CLI tool release page](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/KTX-Software/releases). Select version for your OS and install.
- [CLI tool docs](https://github.khronos.org/KTX-Software/ktxtools/ktx_create.html)

Once installed, something like this seems to work.

```bash
ktx create --encode uastc --zstd 18 --format R8G8B8_SRGB --assign-oetf srgb --assign-primaries bt709 --generate-mipmap source/png/2d_uastc.png ktx2/2d_uastc.ktx2
```

Very complicated CLI tool with ehh documentation but it's probably great if you were looking for a ktx2 CLI tool in the first place. [More example usage](https://github.com/donmccurdy/KTX2-Samples/blob/5765bc9364af5c7b009fc4bbdd41a4d2ca37ffa3/encode.sh#L22)